# Three.js animationData object structure

Tags: animation, three.js, keyframe

I'm trying to hard-code an animation data object for use in a Three.js application. Here's what I have so far in that segment of my code:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper( 1 );
scene.add( axisHelper );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0xffff00
} );
cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

// Setup animation
var animationData = {
    "name"      : "Action",
    "fps"       : 25,
    "length"    : 2.0, 
    "loop"      : true,
    "timescale" : 1,
    "hierarchy" : [
    {
        "parent" : -1, //root
        "keys"   : [
        {
            "time":0,
            "pos" :[0,0,0],
            "rot" :[0,0,0],
            "scl" :[1,1,1]
        },
        {
            "time":1.0,
            "rot" :[0,Math.PI/5,0]
        },
        {
            "time":2.0,
            "rot" :[0,Math.PI/2,0]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
};      

rotationAnimation = new THREE.Animation(cube, animationData);
rotationAnimation.play();
scene.add(cube);
```

When I run the code without the second to last line (or with a .stop() right after it), I get a non-animating cube (as expected). When I play the animation, however, the cube completely disappears without a console error. From everything I can diagnose, this seems to be an issue with my JSON object structure for animationData, but I can't confirm this because the Three.js documentation says nothing about it, and I can find it nowhere but in this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_animation_keys

If anyone could let me know what the issue is here, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: When it comes to dealing with problems with three.js, I've found that it can be particularly helpful to dive down in the (ever changing) source. That should at least give you a clue as to what is going on. In this case, you appear to be missing some keys in the data: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/animation/Animation.js#L64-L71  (and that said, rotating a cube isn't complicated enough to use the animation system, but I guess you are prototyping)

Comment: @Leeft Yes, I'm getting ready to generate more complicated movement. Can you clarify what you mean by "missing some keys in the data"? In the link you give, `prevKey` and `nextKey` are defined within the scope of `THREE.Animation`.